# Where and how does Ubuntu log shellcode attacks?

Tags: command-line, security, logging

If someone enters shell prompt (by exploiting an external shellcode and taking control of the system before running an exploit ) does Ubuntu log messages to `/var/log/lastlog`, `/var/log/wtmp`, `/var/log/kern.log`, `/var/log/syslog` or whatever else? If it does, how do the log message look like? I know only segfault (if core dumped) like this one message in `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jan 10 11:30:02 ubuntu kernel: [10980.811200] bo1[15439]: segfault at 0 ip 001a7210 sp bfbac640 error 4 in ibc-2.11.1.so[134000+153000]
```

Or it does not and we are doomed?

Comment: please, explain your down votes

Comment: "bla bla" might be a clue... Please [edit] and post something that makes sense along with the Ubuntu release/version, a description of what you're trying to do, the expected results and what happens instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no generic way to detect shell code attacks and consequently no canonical log entry pattern for them. If that were possible this kind of attack would pose no danger because intrusion detection systems could reliably detect and thwart them.

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!

Comment: Thank You, David, for Your answer! There is probably then for securing Ubuntu must be working on syscalls level before shell code enters shell prompt. For this purpose there is Systrace with its gtk frontend, but its development was stopped in 2010. @DavidFoerster

Comment: @Dima: Is that supposed to be a question? In any case I can't make much sense of what you're saying.